# What do I have to do to enable the DML replication in the Oracle 18c EE?

Tags: oracle

I have installed the Oracle DB 18c EE. I have installed the Oracle GoldenGate.
My test replication is good.
Then: I have modified the EXTRACT to DDL replication.
But logs say me: You have to prepare the Oracle DB.

The log message:

> 2019-08-02 17:29:05  ERROR   OGG-00529  DDL Replication is enabled but table dima.GGS_DDL_HIST is not found. Please check DDL installation in the database.

There is No Scripts like in the article for the Oracle DB 12 (marker_table, and etc.) in my deployment (18c). DML replication works.

What Do I have to do in a *Oracle **18c** EE* installation to enable the DDL in the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You are using the SQLPlus in the $ORACLE_HOME/bin path You will be using a full path to scripts. All scripts are placed in the **Golden Gate root directory**.

**Use a cd:**

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
cd /home/oracle/ggs/
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

The Full Guide is : [DDL Guide](https://www.vitalsofttech.com/configure-goldengate-ddl-replication/)